# How to duplicate an object in a card by a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with multiple MCQ cards and every one should have an option to add another option if necessary but my current function adds this option to all the cards

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abdotamer3/s57jauxw/11/

My function:

```
$(".TextInputSimpleInputPlaceholder").on("click", function () {
    var clone = $(this).closest(".questionBodyRadioBody").find(".radioListItemPrimaryContent:first").clone(true);
    clone.className = "radioListItemPrimaryContent";
    clone.appendTo(".radioListItemView");
});
```

My cloning function:

```
function cloneQuestion() {
    var question = document.querySelector(".questions");
    var clone = question.cloneNode(true);
    var numItems = $(".questions").closest(".radioListItemPrimaryContent").length;
    var radioButtons = question.querySelectorAll(".radioItemToggle");
    console.log(numItems);
    clone.querySelector(".questionMainTextArea").value = "Untitled Question";
    var addBtn = document.querySelector(".addQuestionBtnRow");
    var tbody = addBtn.parentNode;
    tbody.insertBefore(clone, addBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should add scope to your selector:

```
var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
$clone.appendTo($(".radioListItemView", $card));
```

Also Option numbering should be per card I think.

```js
$(".TextInputSimpleInputPlaceholder").on("click", function () {
    var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
    var numItems = $(".radioListItemPrimaryContent", $card).length;
    var $clone = $(this).closest(".questionBodyRadioBody").find(".radioListItemPrimaryContent:first").clone(true);
    $clone.className = "radioListItemPrimaryContent";
    $clone.find(".optionText").val("Option " + numItems);
    numItems++;
    $clone.appendTo($(".radioListItemView", $card));
});
```

```css
.card {
  border-radius: .5rem !important;
  width: 45rem;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem !important;
}

.form_frame td {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.FormHeaderBorder {
  background-color: #673ab7;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-selector {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 8px;
}

.card-selector-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-selector-color {
  background-color: transparent;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.viewItemActive .card-selector-color {
  background-color: #4285f4;
}

.viewItemActive .questionMainTextAreaContent {
  display: block;
}

.viewItemInactive .questionMainTextAreaContent {
  display: none;
}

.questionMainTextAreaContent {
  padding-top: 16px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.questionMainTextAreaContentArea {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.viewItemActive .questionHeader {
  display: none;
}

.viewItemInactive .questionHeader {
  display: block;
}

.questionMainTextArea {
  height: 24px;
  font-family: 'Google Sans', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  caret-color: #1a73e8;
  display: block;
  min-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0 16px 16px;
  resize: none;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  z-index: 1;
}

.questionMainTextAreaUnderline {
  background-color: #80868b;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.questionMainTextArea:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width .3s ease 0s, left .3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.questionMainTextArea:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.questionBodyRadioBody {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.radioListItemView {
  min-height: 48px;
  background: #fff;
}

.radioListItemPrimaryContent {
  -moz-box-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.radioListItemGutter {
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 48px;
}

.radioListTypeIndicator {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #202124;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input.radioItemToggle {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  transition: border-color .2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.radioListItemEditRegion {
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.radioListValue {
  flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.radioListMorseValue {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.radioListItemValueInput {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
}

.TextInputSimpleInputContentArea {
  display: flex;
}

.radioListItemValueInput .exportInput {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #202124;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.TextInputSimpleInput {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  font: 400 16px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: .125em 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.viewItemActive .radioListItemPrimaryContent:hover .exportUnderline,
.TextInputSimpleInputUnderline {
  visibility: visible;
}

.viewItemActive .radioListItemPrimaryContent:focus-within .exportUnderline,
.TextInputSimpleInputUnderline {
  visibility: visible;
}

.radioListItemValueInput .exportUnderline {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.TextInputSimpleInputUnderline {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radioListItemGhostItemInput {
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
}

.TextInputSimpleInputMainContent {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.TextInputSimpleInputPlaceholder {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #70757a;
}

.viewItemActive .itemHideInactive {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card MCQuestion viewItemActive">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="questionMainTextAreaContent">
          <div class="questionMainTextAreaContentArea">
            <textarea class="questionMainTextArea" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question title" dir="auto"></textarea>
            <div class="questionMainTextAreaUnderline"></div>
            <div class="questionMainTextAreaFocusUnderline"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title questionHeader"></div>
        <div class="questionBodyRadioBody">
          <div class="radioListItemView">
            <div class="radioListItemPrimaryContent">
              <div class="radioListItemGutter">
                <div class="radioListTypeIndicator">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-0" class="radioItemToggle">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="radioListItemEditRegion">
                <div class="radioListValue">
                  <div class="radioListMorseValue">
                    <span>
                      <div class="radioListItemValueInput">
                        <div class="TextInputSimpleInputContentArea">
                          <input class="TextInputSimpleInput exportInput optionText" type="text" value="Option 1" tabindex="0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="TextInputSimpleInputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
                      </div>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="itemHideInactive radioListItemPrimaryContent">
            <div class="radioListItemGutter">
              <div class="radioListTypeIndicator">
                <input type="radio" class="radioItemToggle" aria-checked="false" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="radioListItemGhostItemInput">
              <div class="TextInputSimpleInputMainContent">
                <div class="TextInputSimpleInputPlaceholder" role="button">
                  <div class="TextInputSimpleInputContentArea">
                    <div class="TextInputSimpleInput exportInput optionText">
                      Add option
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="TextInputSimpleInputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card MCQuestion viewItemActive">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="questionMainTextAreaContent">
          <div class="questionMainTextAreaContentArea">
            <textarea class="questionMainTextArea" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question title" dir="auto"></textarea>
            <div class="questionMainTextAreaUnderline"></div>
            <div class="questionMainTextAreaFocusUnderline"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title questionHeader"></div>
        <div class="questionBodyRadioBody">
          <div class="radioListItemView">
            <div class="radioListItemPrimaryContent">
              <div class="radioListItemGutter">
                <div class="radioListTypeIndicator">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-0" class="radioItemToggle">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="radioListItemEditRegion">
                <div class="radioListValue">
                  <div class="radioListMorseValue">
                    <span>
                      <div class="radioListItemValueInput">
                        <div class="TextInputSimpleInputContentArea">
                          <input class="TextInputSimpleInput exportInput optionText" type="text" value="Option 1" tabindex="0">
                        </div>
                        <div class="TextInputSimpleInputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
                      </div>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="radioListMorselRoot itemHideInactive">
                <div class="radioListMorselDeleteButton" aria-label="Remove Option">
                  <span class="ButtonContent">
                    <span>
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="#5f6368" d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path>
                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="itemHideInactive radioListItemPrimaryContent">
            <div class="radioListItemGutter">
              <div class="radioListTypeIndicator">
                <input type="radio" class="radioItemToggle" aria-checked="false" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="radioListItemGhostItemInput">
              <div class="TextInputSimpleInputMainContent">
                <div class="TextInputSimpleInputPlaceholder" role="button">
                  <div class="TextInputSimpleInputContentArea">
                    <div class="TextInputSimpleInput exportInput optionText">
                      Add option
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="TextInputSimpleInputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This function only works on existing cards but any cloned cards dont work

Comment: You never mentioned you will clone the cards but and there's no code you provided how you clone a card. Probably after cloning you don't have your click handler attached. The function doesn't make any difference if your card is cloned or not.

Comment: I saw your edit, but ...` var question = document.querySelector(".questions");` you don't have `questions` html provided ... please include all required. I'm not sure if tag holding `.questions` has your click handler assigned

Comment: I have edited the fiddle to include the whole html needed

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using pure JavaScript while jQuery is present, but as I told the method you are using to clone the card is not deeply copying the events assigned. I've just changed it to a proper way of copying w/ handlers i.e. `var clone = $(question).clone(true, true).get(0);`. Read the jQuery help for that. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nz2q6re4/

Comment: If you think these efforts to help you are really helpful you may vote up the answer and if you think this is the best answer you may green tick it as best answer.